# Invoking native share dialog from webpage in mobile webbrowser?

Tags: android, ios, api, mobile, browser

Most web browsers provide option to share the webpage using the native sharing capability of OS. Can we invoke it from a webpage i.e. when a user clicks a button then the native share dialog of browser opens. Maybe the individual browsers provide independent APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit tricky, you will need to send an intent with the share data, so I think it should be similar in all the browsers.

Check this article out: https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/